# Windows 10 blocking piratebay

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, dns, firewall

Yesterday I installed windows 10 on my new SSD. Everything went fine until I tried to access [thepiratebay.org](https://thepiratebay.org/index.html) or any other of its clones. I tried it in chrome and received an error: *this site cant be reached (err_connection_refused)*.

**Things I tried already, and all have failed:**

- Using other browsers
- Turning off firewall in control panel
- Uninstalling my Antivirus
- Changing my DNS
- Disable "use a proxy server for my lan"
- Adding site to trusted sites
- Lowering security level in control panel
- Network reset in windows settings

In the Command Prompt I ran the following commands:

- `netsh int ip reset C:\Resetlog.txt`
- `netsh winsock reset`
- `ipconfig /flushdns`

I set up Oracle VM to test it and it worked so my ISP nor my router is blocking it. The error has to be somewhere in my windows. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Check Windows Defender (System Tray) Smart Screen and Smart Screen settings. That is likely what blocked it

Comment: I tried that, turned off all the smart screen options, still doesnt work. What is weird is that 1337x is working, just piratebay is not

Comment: What exactly is 1337x?

Comment: There are a number of Windows Defender settings in about 7 categories. It would be worth your while to check through all the settings (a) to see if you find another block and (b) to become familiar with all the settings.

Comment: @Ramhound another torrent search engine

Comment: @John i tried everything i could click on in windows settings as well as control panel. I found nothing more that can be turned off or changed

Comment: Please double-check this is actually an OS problem by using a different OS (for example, a  Linux live-ISO on USB). I think Windows has nothing to do with it. You didn't specify what OS you had running in your Oracle VM.

Comment: @Ramhound - 1337x is a torrent listing site like the Pirate Bay.

Comment: @GBoGH - What DNS provider are you using?

Comment: Check hosts file and try different DNS?  Router as well, just hop on hotspot real quick and see if it loads, etc.  You can also try a utility/SaaS like [Ooni](https://ooni.org/nettest/).

Comment: Just use a VPN, that would do the job

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the hosts file, some stupid Microsoft manager inserted all these sites to be blocked.
Edit with notepad or any text editor and delete all this garbage.

Now Chrome and Firefox work. No Need to Reboot.

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts  (no file extensions)

You will need to change the right access to save over (overwrite) this file.

```
127.0.0.1       thepiratebay.org
127.0.0.1       www.thepiratebay.org
127.0.0.1       pirateproxy.surf
127.0.0.1       www.pirateproxy.surf
127.0.0.1       pirateproxy.ink
127.0.0.1       www.pirateproxy.ink
127.0.0.1       openpirate.org
127.0.0.1       www.openpirate.org
127.0.0.1       mypiratebay.club
127.0.0.1       www.mypiratebay.club
127.0.0.1       openpirate.cc
127.0.0.1       www.openpirate.cc
127.0.0.1       mypiratebay.net
127.0.0.1       www.mypiratebay.net
127.0.0.1       mypiratebay.wtf
127.0.0.1       www.mypiratebay.wtf
127.0.0.1       tpb.cool
127.0.0.1       www.tpb.cool
127.0.0.1       piratebay.icu
127.0.0.1       www.piratebay.icu
127.0.0.1       tpb.red
127.0.0.1       www.tpb.red
127.0.0.1       piratebay.life
127.0.0.1       www.piratebay.life
127.0.0.1       mypiratebay.fun
127.0.0.1       www.mypiratebay.fun
127.0.0.1       mypiratebay.co
127.0.0.1       www.mypiratebay.co
127.0.0.1       piratebay.tech
127.0.0.1       www.piratebay.tech
127.0.0.1       mypiratebay.life
127.0.0.1       www.mypiratebay.life
127.0.0.1       mypiratebay.me
127.0.0.1       www.mypiratebay.me
127.0.0.1       mypiratebay.best
127.0.0.1       www.mypiratebay.best
127.0.0.1       tpb.bike
127.0.0.1       www.tpb.bike
127.0.0.1       tpb.email
127.0.0.1       www.tpb.email
127.0.0.1       tpb.guru
127.0.0.1       www.tpb.guru
127.0.0.1       thepiratebay3.to
127.0.0.1       www.thepiratebay3.to
127.0.0.1       pirate-bay.net
127.0.0.1       www.pirate-bay.net
127.0.0.1       thepiratebay.zone
127.0.0.1       www.thepiratebay.zone
127.0.0.1       pirateproxy.live
127.0.0.1       www.pirateproxy.live
127.0.0.1       thepiratebay10.org
127.0.0.1       www.thepiratebay10.org
127.0.0.1       piratebay.live
127.0.0.1       www.piratebay.live
127.0.0.1       tpb.party
127.0.0.1       www.tpb.party
127.0.0.1       piratebayproxy.live
127.0.0.1       www.piratebayproxy.live
127.0.0.1       thehiddenbay.com
127.0.0.1       www.thehiddenbay.com
127.0.0.1       thepiratebay9.net
127.0.0.1       www.thepiratebay9.net
127.0.0.1       unblocktheship.org
127.0.0.1       www.unblocktheship.org
127.0.0.1       thepiratebay.wiki
127.0.0.1       www.thepiratebay.wiki
127.0.0.1       pirateproxy-bay.com
127.0.0.1       www.pirateproxy-bay.com
127.0.0.1       pirateproxy.wtf
127.0.0.1       www.pirateproxy.wtf
127.0.0.1       proxybay.uk
127.0.0.1       www.proxybay.uk
127.0.0.1       tpblist.info
127.0.0.1       www.tpblist.info
127.0.0.1       tpblist.org
127.0.0.1       www.tpblist.org
127.0.0.1       tpbaysproxy.com
127.0.0.1       www.tpbaysproxy.com
127.0.0.1       heypirateproxy.com
127.0.0.1       www.heypirateproxy.com
127.0.0.1       xtorrentp2p.com
127.0.0.1       www.xtorrentp2p.com
127.0.0.1       pirateproxy.tk
127.0.0.1       www.pirateproxy.tk
127.0.0.1       thepirate-bay.org
127.0.0.1       www.thepirate-bay.org
127.0.0.1       thepiratbays.org
127.0.0.1       www.thepiratbays.org
127.0.0.1       thepiratebay.cx
127.0.0.1       www.thepiratebay.cx
127.0.0.1       thepiratebays.com.se
127.0.0.1       www.thepiratebays.com.se
127.0.0.1       thepiratebay.app
127.0.0.1       www.thepiratebay.app
127.0.0.1       piratebay-proxy-list.com
127.0.0.1       www.piratebay-proxy-list.com
127.0.0.1       bestsevenreviews.com
127.0.0.1       www.bestsevenreviews.com
127.0.0.1       creativepixelmag.com
127.0.0.1       www.creativepixelmag.com
127.0.0.1       thepiratebays.com
127.0.0.1       www.thepiratebays.com
127.0.0.1       tpbproxypirate.com
127.0.0.1       www.tpbproxypirate.com
127.0.0.1       tpbproxypirate.com
127.0.0.1       www.tpbproxypirate.com
```

Microsoft is like Ford the longer it lives the more crap it brings to our environment.

Comment: Which "Microsoft manager" is that?

Answer (score 0):

Many popular torrent sites are blocked by the main DNS servers of many
countries, depending upon local legislation. Your country must be one of those.

The only solution is to use a VPN server positioned in a country where
torrenting is allowed, so that it does not block these domains in its
main DNS server(s).

You could try using the IP address of these sites without a VPN,
rather than their domain name, and this might be enough to work around
this restriction.
Just remember that your country frowns upon using these services.

Comment: Most or all UK ISPs block torrent sites. The way around that is to use [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/) or else configure a spare machine on your LAN as a Tor proxy (a raspberry Pi is fine for this).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Tor is a possibility, but usually with much lower bandwidth than VPN.

Comment: You only need Tor to get the torrent link, or magnet link. Once you have that, and provide it (paste) to the torrent software (Deluge, uTorrent, Vuse, whatever) the rest works just fine without VPN or Tor. Torrent sites don't actually provide the downloaded material.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Some countries block better, so the torrent client does not find any sources. I never looked into how they do that.

Comment: I dont think it is because of the laws, because it literally stopped working overnight. I did it using tor and now it works. I will call my ISP tomorrow

Comment: I guess that may be where the VPN comes in. In Britain, we seem to have a typical compromise, which is "we'll try to stop you finding any torrent links, but if you do, fill your boots". One thing to watch out for is that if you do not use a VPN to do the actual downloading, your IP address is exposed to anyone using a torrent client to see who else is downloading a file, and that 'anyone' includes lawyers for film studios, who might write to your ISP. This seems mainly confined to very recent, mass-market movies.

Comment: “I set up Oracle VM to test it and it worked so my ISP nor my router is blocking it.” - This tells me that the author’s ISP isn’t blocking the website.  What this actually tells me is that the author’s DNS provider is to blame. This is the reason the VM worked, it wasn’t using the same DNS server, has the host VM.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found out that my DNS provider is the same as my ISP, so i have to contact them anyways